# I have an issue with a non-static method

Tags: java

I have a `Student` class with the following instance variables:

```
int code;
String surname, firstname, major;
```

In the `main` method (in a second class), I created `Student` objects, and I added them to a `Vector`. In the class containing the `main` method, I defined two additional methods:

```
public static boolean search(List list, int code)
public static void display(List list)
```

I'd like to create another method now (`Student getStudent(int code)`) which would return a `Student` object based on the code passed as the argument.

What I don't understand is that we're asked not to make this a static method like the other two. Furthermore, I can't manage to search for the `Student` given the code, because I don't have the list, which is created in the `main` method, as an argument!

I need some guidance in all this.

Here are some of my code snippets :

```
public class Etudiant {


int code;
String nom, prenom, filiere;

Etudiant() { 
    this.code = 0;
    this.nom = "";
    this.prenom = "";
    this.filiere = "";  }

Etudiant(int code, String nom, String prenom, String filiere){
    this.code = code;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.filiere = filiere; }

public String toString(){   return code + "; " + nom + "; " + prenom + "; " + filiere +  "\n";  }   

public int getCode() {  return code;    }

public String getFiliere() {    return filiere; }

public void setCode(int code) { this.code = code;   }

public void setNom(String nom) {    this.nom = nom; }

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {  this.prenom = prenom;   }

public void setFiliere(String filiere) {    this.filiere = filiere; }
}
```

And here are some snippets of the Main method

```
public class TestListe { 

public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList <Etudiant> liste = new ArrayList <Etudiant> ();


    Etudiant e1 = new Etudiant(326, "Fouhami", "Aimen", "LOGISTIQUE");
    Etudiant e2 = new Etudiant(258, "Ait Taleb", "Souad", "INFORMATIQUE");
    Etudiant e3 = new Etudiant(789, "Elouardi", "Nadia", "ENERGIES RENOUVLABLES");
    Etudiant e4 = new Etudiant(25, "MEKKAOUI", "Oumaima", "IBPM");  

    liste.add(e1);
    liste.add(e2);
    liste.add(e3);
    liste.add(e4);  

}

// AFFICHAGE DE LA LISTE DES ETUDIANTS
public static void affichage(List <Etudiant> liste){`

            for(int i = 0; i<liste.size(); i++){
                System.out.print(liste.get(i));
            }

        }
// RECHERCHE D'UN ETUDIANT PAR LE CODE
public static boolean recherche(List liste, int code){
            int i = 0;
            Etudiant e;

            do{
                e = (Etudiant) liste.get(i);
                i++;

            }   while(i<liste.size() && e.getCode() != code);


            if(e.getCode() == code) return true;

            else return false;  
        }
```

Comment: En Anglais s'il vous plait

Comment: Now that's the most useful edit I've seen.

Comment: Could you please post some code snippets for us?

Comment: Yes of course, Bruno. I've edited my post for you by adding some snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need another class.

You have your `Student` class, that's great. But you need a class that acts as your `StudentManager`

```
public class StudentManager {
    List<Student> list;
    public StudentManager(List<Student> list) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(list); // make a defensive copy
    }
    public Student getStudent(int code) {
        for(Student s : list) {
            if(s.getCode() == code) {
                return s;
            }
        }
        return null; // or something to indicate not found
    }
}
```

Now in your main method, you can do this:

```
List<Student> list = ... // make the list
StudentManager man = new StudentManager(list);
Student s = man.getStudent(1234);
```

The advantage of this is you might have multiple lists, and you can create mutliple student managers based on those lists. For example

```
StudentManager engineering = new StudentManager(engineeringList);
StudentManager gradStudents = new StudentManager(gradStudentList);

Student s = getCorsika(); // that's me!!!
engineering.getStudent(s.getCode()); // finds me, because I'm an engineer
gradStudents.getStudent(s.getCode()); // doesn't find me, because I'm not a grad student
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you can't search for the student if you have no reference to the list. The only way to do this, is to give the list to the method(as parameter). An other way is to save a reference to the list as attribute in every student, when he is added to the list.

If the list(as Vector) is saved in a static way (public static vector x) you can access it from everywhere:

`public class c
{
    public static Vector liste;
}`

then  you can do:

`Vector liste = c.liste;`

---

French(very bad):

C'est vrai! Tu a besoin d'un reference de la liste. Il te faut d'avair ça comme un parameter. Tu peut aussi mettre un reference de la liste dans chaque etudiant.

Une autre solution, fait la comme ça:

`public class c
{
    public static Vector liste;
}`

`Vector liste = c.liste;`

Comment: Tout à fait ! Merci beaucoup.